# Multiple classNames with CSS Modules and React

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I'm using the following code to dynamically set a className in a React component based upon a boolean from props:

```
<div className={this.props.menuOpen ? 'inactive' : 'active'}>
...
</div>
```

However, I'm also using CSS Modules, so now I need to set the className to:

```
import styles from './styles.css';

<div className={styles.sideMenu}>
...
</div>
```

I'm having trouble with this - I tried using [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) to gain more control with multiple classes, but because I need the end result to be that the className is set to both `styles.sideMenu` **AND** `styles.active` (in order for CSS Modules to kick in) I'm unsure how to handle this.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't `classnames` work for you? This is the case it's designed for.

Comment: I got this far with `classnames`:

```let classNames = classnames(styles.sideMenu, {
      active: this.props.menuOpen,
    });
```
However, the key `active` must be `styles.active` (so that I can place my css in the imported stylesheet), and setting to this creates an error. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the documentation?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Using [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) and es6:

```
let classNames = classnames(styles.sideMenu, { [styles.active]: this.props.menuOpen });
```

Using `classnames` and es5:

```
var classNames = classnames(styles.sideMenu, this.props.menuOpen ? styles.active : '');
```

Comment: { [styles.active]: this.props.menuOpen } what is the syntax? i can't find it in es6

Comment: @FroDK They're called computed property names. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015

Answer (score 23):

Bit late to the party here, but using string templates works for me - you could move the ternary operator out to a const if you'd like as well:

```
<div className={`${styles.sideMenu} ${this.props.menuOpen ? styles.inactive : styles.active}`>
...
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  FYI: you missed a } at the end.

Comment: I appreciate this solution because it doesn't need an import.

Comment: Great thanks. This is much handier.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to just add on a better way of using the `bind` api of `classnames` npm. You can bind the classnames to the styles object imported from css like below:

```
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';
import styles from './index.css';

let cx = classNames.bind(styles);
```

and use it like this:

```
cx("sideMenu", "active": isOpen)
```

where sideMenu and active are in styles object.

Answer (score 3):

Using logical `AND` instead of ternary operator makes it even less verbose since `classnames` omits a falsy value.

```
<div className={ classNames(styles.sideMenu, this.props.menuOpen && styles.active) }></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I can get to a working solution:

`const isActive = this.props.menuOpen ? styles.inactive :  styles.active;`

`<div className={isActive + ' ' + styles.sideMenu}>`

This does work - both allow the styles in the imported stylesheet to be used, and is only applied when `this.props.menuOpen` is `true`.

However, it's pretty hacky - I'd love to see a better solution if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Array.join`**

`<div className={[styles.sideMenu, this.props.menuOpen ? styles.show : styles.hide].join(' ')}></div>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not an expert on CSS modules, I did find this documentation: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/blob/master/docs/import-multiple-css-modules.md

It appears that you'll need to combine the styles for `active` and `sideMenu` together using `Object.assign`

Comment: I fiddled around with this - but I'm not sure I see what the target would be in this case - I need a class added based upon a boolean in props, and a class from the css module, and both should be prefixed with `styles.`.

Answer (score 0):

`import classNames from 'classnames/bind'`.

then you can use like this:
`let cx = classNames.bind(styles);`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

In case like that `styles['bar-item-active']` , you can wrap it . in second square brackets like `[styles['bar-item-active']] : your condition`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone has suggested using both the style and the className attributes in your React DOM element:

```
const sideMenu={backgroundColour:'blue',
                border:'1px black solid'}

return <>
  <div style={sideMenu} className={this.props.menuOpen ? styles.inactive : styles.active}>
  ...
  </div>
</>
```

It's not the neatest solution, but it does avoid adding another dependency to your project and if your sideMenu class is small then it could be a option

Answer (score 0):

Using [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) library

```
import classNames from "classnames";
```

`classNames` is a function. if you pass some strings, it joins them together if they all are truthy. If there is any `falsy` string it will not pass it. For example

```
 let textColor=undefined
 classNames(textColor, "px-2","py-2" )
```

since `textColor` variable is falsy, `classNames` will ignore it and returns this string

```
"px-2 py-2"
```

You can also pass an object to `classNames` function.

```
 const active=true
 const foo=false
```

Let's say I have this expression

```
classNames({
    'text-green':active,
     'text-yellow':foo
})
```

`classNames` function will look at "VALUE" of each pair. if the "value" is `truthy`, it will take the "KEY" but if the "VALUE" is `falsy` it will ignore the "KEY". In this example since "active" true and "foo" is false it will return this string

```
 'text-green'
```

In your example, you want to add a className based on if the prop is `truth` or `falsy` in other words if the prop exists or not:

```
let classNames=classNames(
    styles.sideMenu,
    // based on props that you are passing you can define dynamic classnames in your component
    {
      "active":this.props.menuOpen
    }
  )
```