# How can I rewrite this conditional css using classnames?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, class-names

In react component, I'm using css module and I got this conditional css that is working fine, but I would like to refactor it using classnames library.

```
className = { `${active ? styles.activeLabel : styles.notActiveLabel} 
${weight === 'bold' ? styles.bold : ''}`}
```

So I tried this but I get error msg saying active will always return false.

```
className={classnames({styles.activeLabel: !!active}, {styles.bold: weight === 'bold'})}
```

I also tried styles.activeLabel: active === true,  but I get another error message.
Basically I want when active prop is true then apply activeLabel class, if active is false then apply notActiveLabel class. How can I accomplish this using classnames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Keys on JS Object must to be a string or a number, you can't set a key like:

```
// this does not work
const object = { key: 'value' }
const object2 = { object.key: true }
```

So, when you need to get a key with dynamic name you have to do with square brackets

```
// this works
const object = { key: 'value' }
const object2 = { [object.key]: true }
```

Try to do something like:

```
className={classnames({ [styles.activeLabel]: !!active}, {[styles.bold]: weight === 'bold'})}
```

References:
[Multiple classNames with CSS Modules and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382153/multiple-classnames-with-css-modules-and-react)
[How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)